# L'hospitals Rule applications

Tags: calculus

let $f(x)=x^2sin\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=sinx$

The book says that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists. How come?

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{x^2sin\frac{1}{x}}{sinx}$$

as $x\to 0$ $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to\frac{0}{0}$ Or is this discontinuity removable? If so , I couldn't remove it.

I'm not using l'hospitals rule since limit of $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ does not exist.

Comment: Did you try using L'hospitals Rule ?

Comment: Check the edit please, :)

Comment: $\sin x \sim x$ so you're evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} x \sin x$. Squeeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L’Hôpital’s theorem says that, under certain initial hypotheses (look at your textbook for them), if
$$
\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\tag{*}
$$
exists (finite or infinite) and is $l$, then also
$$
\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l
$$

However it says nothing if the limit (*) doesn't exist, which is precisely the case at hand.

> L’Hôpital’s theorem ***doesn't say*** that
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
> $$
>   when the initial hypotheses are satisfied.